# Defining a SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need help with the following SQL procedure I am trying to define inside of SQL Management Studio.  There are a bunch of highlights telling me that the syntax is wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Errors:

> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertNonExistingNode, Line 5
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

```
USE NWatchEntitiesUnitTest

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNonExistingNode (@TableVariable dbo.NodeTypeTable READONLY, 
                                        @ScalarParameter nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO NWatchNodes WITH (ROWLOCK) (NodeTypeId,
      Location,
      DisplayName,
      AccessLevel,
      IsEnabled,
      CreatedOn,
      CreatedBy,
      ModifiedOn,
      ModifiedBy,
      NativeId,
      SourceId,
      Name,
      Alias) 

    SELECT Name,
    Location,
      DisplayName,
      AccessLevel,
      IsEnabled,
      CreatedOn,
      CreatedBy,
      ModifiedOn,
      ModifiedBy,
      NativeId,
      SourceId,
      Name,
      Alias

    FROM @TableVariable t
        /*Left Join then where ID is null to make sure the record doesn't exists*/
        LEFT JOIN NWatchNodes PR WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                ON  PR.ID = @ScalarParameter
                                AND PR.Name = t.Name
        WHERE PR.ID IS NULL
END

GO
```

Comment: "*There are a bunch of highlights telling me that the syntax is wrong*".... well . you could show some of them at least.

Comment: Apart from the highlights, does the query execute successfully?

Comment: It does not, but I just added the first error.  Sorry about that.

Comment: use "Go" after "USE NWatchEntitiesUnitTest" line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error text is self-explanatory. Since `CREATE PROCEDURE` should be first statement in a batch - then just add `GO` after `USE` statement, thus you will break it to the two batches - first one setting current DB and second one creating procedure itself.

```
USE NWatchEntitiesUnitTest
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will add the next error in a separate question.